# How to unpack gzip QueryResponse in twitter api wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter, gzip

I have problem like this https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4563

```
               if (webResponse.Headers["Content-Encoding"] == "gzip")
                {
                    byte[] bytes = UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stream);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    var rstream = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipInputStream(ms);
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(rstream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        var st = reader.ReadToEnd();// Exception here: "Error baseInputStream GZIP header,  second byte doesn't match"
                        parameters = HelperMethods.GetQueryParameters(st);
                    }
                }
```

I use this lib: http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/

**Update:**
I use RestClient for post tweet only. For login I use:

```
var AccessTokenQuery = oAuthHelper.GetAccessTokenQuery(OAuthTokenKey, tokenSecret, VerifyPin);
            AccessTokenQuery.QueryResponse += new EventHandler<WebQueryResponseEventArgs>(AccessTokenQuery_QueryResponse);
            AccessTokenQuery.RequestAsync(TwitterSettings.AccessTokenUri, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the gzip response you are receiving isn't quite what SharpZipLib is expecting.

The error you are getting is from [SharpZipLib/src/GZIP/GzipInputStream.cs](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/src/GZip/GzipInputStream.cs) and is probably from this line:

```
if (magic != (GZipConstants.GZIP_MAGIC & 0xFF)) {
                throw new GZipException("Error GZIP header,  second magic byte doesn't match");
}
```

Try saving the stream to a file and then take a look at it. See if you can unpack it with 7-zip, etc. Then once you know what's wrong you can go from there.

### Update:

There appears to be a solution to the problem you are having at the end of [the discussion you linked to](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4563) and I wanted to make sure you were aware of it:

> @SMCApps 
>   I caught a break...
>
> ```
> Dim client = New RestClient() With { _
> .Authority = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth", _
> .Credentials = credentials, _
> .HasElevatedPermissions = True, _
> .SilverlightAcceptEncodingHeader = "gzip", _
> .DecompressionMethods = Silverlight.Compat.DecompressionMethods.GZip _
> }
> ```

Comment: when I set this: DecompressionMethods =Hammock.Silverlight.Compat.DecompressionMethods.GZip, I had exception in Hammock

Comment: NullReferenceException, Call Stack location: Hammock.WindowsPhone.dll!Hammock.Silverlight.Compat.GzipHttpwebResponse.GetResponseStream() + 0x1c bytes

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I solved it by updating the Hammock to latest version.
You can get it at http://nuget.org/packages/Hammock

After updating, It worked only when I commented the

```
DecompressionMethods =Hammock.Silverlight.Compat.DecompressionMethods.GZip
```

line from my Oauth request. I'm not sure how n why?